# Is $\cos$ a polynomial function of $\sin$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials

We know that $\cos^2$ is a polynomial function of $\sin$ because
$$\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x.$$
But this left me wondering: Does there exist a polynomial function $P$ such that
$$\cos x=P(\sin x)?$$
Can we prove it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This polynomial $P$ would have to satisfy
$$ z^2 + P(z)^2 = 1 $$
But if $P$ had degree $d > 1$, $z^2 + P(z)^2$ would have degree $2d$.  And degree $0$ or $1$ clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 19):

There is no polynomial (or any function) $P$ such that $\cos(x) = P(\sin(x))$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Because that function would have to satisfy
$$
 P(0) = P(\sin(0)) = \cos(0) = 1
$$
and
$$
 P(0) = P(\sin(\pi)) = \cos(\pi) = -1
$$